# graphql: Use GraphQLObjectType to create a type that extends a Mutation

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm using the graphql npm package to build up a graphql schema that includes a mutation that looks like this:

```
type Mutation {
  cxUnitCosts_onSave(data: [CxUnitCostInput]): [CxUnitCost]
}
```

which I do like this, assuming I have an input and output variables containing GraphQLObjectTypes:

```
new GraphQLObjectType({
      name:  'Mutation',
      fields: {
        [camelcase(output.toString())+'s_onSave']: {
          args: {data: {type: new GraphQLList(input)},
        },
          type:  new GraphQLList(output)
        }
      }
    })
```

**But what I want is to extend the type mutation to produce something like this:**

```
extend type Mutation {
  cxUnitCosts_onSave(data: [CxUnitCostInput]): [CxUnitCost]
}
```

I need to extend Mutation because I am merging together a large number of schema programmatically generated from JSON Schema (many dozens of cxFoo...)  If I don't extend the mutation, only one survives the merge.

I would rather not use String manipulation as in the answer below and I would prefer not to have to do the merging manually. I don't want to have to look inside the schema.

For the life of me I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do something along these lines:

```
const { parse, GraphQLSchema } = require('graphql')
const { extendSchema } = require('graphql/utilities)

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: queryType,
});

const extension = `extend type Foo {
  someNewField: String
}`;

const extendedSchema = extendSchema(schema, parse(extension));
```

But... for a mutation or anything requiring a custom resolver, you would still have to add the resolver back in with something like `addResolveFunctionsToSchema` from `graphql-tools`.

You can easily extend types if you write your schema using SDL, write your resolvers separately and then create the schema with `makeExecutableSchema` instead of defining the schema programatically.

If you provide more context around why you're extending the schema or what you're trying to accomplish, I might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: I added a bit of context.  I'm pretty committed to the path of defining the schema programatically. I'm transforming a bunch of json schema and I really don't want to be emitting strings to do that.

Comment: At the end of the day, you just need a single object with properties that map to your Mutation field names. Maybe I'm missing something. Is there a reason you can't reduce your json schema to an object like that, and then finally pass that object in to the constructor for your Mutation type?

Comment: I could, I suppose.  I have many json schema that I process independently and would rather merge them together using the graphql tools and not have to look inside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sad I didn't get an answer to my question.  What I wound up doing was, in the penultimate step of my pipeline, just before I write the schema to the file,  I replace the strings.

```
replace('type Mutation', 'extend type Mutation'),
replace('type Query', 'extend type Query'),
```

I guess that's how it goes sometimes. I'm still surprised this isn't doable programmatically.